# Why is UIButton frame setting so slow

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instruments

Lately I have been doing some performance analysis on instruments for an app. This is what I noticed:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Namely the UIButton frame setting is very slow.

To rule out the probability that it is caused by type casting (from int to CGFloat), I have tried the following:

[image: pic3]

I have also tried:

[image: pic4]

Nope, not much help either.

Last but not least I have made sure it is not caused by CGRectMake:

[image: pic5]

The function has been called roughly 650-670 times, which makes each frame setting call roughly 0.173ms? Does that sound right? How could I improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... I'm not 100% sure but you're using button type `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` which has a fixed size.

Try just setting the centre of it instead of the frame.

```
myDetailButton.center = CGPointMake(12, 12);
```

instead of ...

```
myDetailButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
```

Also the `f` is not required and IIRC it actually can take more memory than necessary when used. Just use `23` or `23.0` instead of `23.0f`. I'll have to find a reference for this though.

**EDIT**

Having said that I just saw your timing stats at the bottom of the question.

The percentages you are seeing here are relative. 0.173ms is almost no time at all.

You might get a better performance improvement by not running the function so many times. You're running it 700 times. Thats a LOT! Do you really need to run it that many times. You can't even fit that many buttons onto the screen at once.

Maybe you need to dequeue them instead? You're using an `MKMapView` after all.

Comment: what do you mean by dequeue them?

Comment: Well I'd need to see more of your code to work out what you're trying to do with the buttons. The way a tableView and collection view manage their cells is the same way that a map manages the annotation views. If a table has 100 items but only 10 are on the screen then it only creates 10 cells. Then when a cell leaves the screen that cell is marked as available again for the next item so there are only ever 10 cells. It would make sense to do something like this instead of load 700 buttons into memory. Only have enough to display on the screen and reuse them.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but it is kind of hard because 600+ results were returned by the server on the first query, so unless I change how the query is handled, it can not be solved easily.

Comment: You can still have an array with 600 items. But just load buttons for the ones that are actually on the screen at any given point.